# Can I use same certificate and provisioning profile to add version of my app on iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I have created an app and upload it on iTunes Connect. But now I want to add version of my app in iTunes Connect. I have created a certificate and provisioning profile to upload my app on iTunes Connect the first time, and now I want to add a new version. Should I use the same provisioning profile and certificate to upload the app?

And also the distribution certificate are created on client's mac, so do I have to change anything in my project to use client's distribution certificate in my mac?

**UPDATE**

When I use the client's P12 file than should I have to delete my own developer certificate and distribution certificate from my mac? and only use the client's developer certificate and distribution certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you can use same certificate file for version changes.

Developer profile valid for 6 months. and distribution profile valid for 1 year.

Step 1: To export your private key and certificate for development on multiple systems, open up the Keychain Access Application and select the ‘Keys’ category.

Step 2: Select the private key associated with your iPhone Development Certificate and click ‘Export Items’ in the menu. The private key is identified by the iPhone Developer: public certificate that is paired with it.

Step 3: Save your key in the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file format.

Step 4: If you want Create a password which is used when you attempt to import this key on another computer.

Step 5: You can use this .p12 file multiple systems. Double-click  .p12 to install . You will be prompted for the password you entered in Step 4.

same thing for distribution file.

Comment: all the file you can use. your developer profile valid 6 months and distribution profile valid 1 year

Comment: i edited my answer check it. that steps are operation from your client machine. then only you can use that profile in your system.

Comment: when i use cliet's P12 file than should i have to delete my own developer certificate and distribution certificate from my mac? and use only client's developer certificate and distribution certificate?

Comment: if you have trouble at the run time. you may delete those file in your system. before that you can also take the .p12 file it is safer.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you have to use the same Provisioning profile and certificate to upload the versions of an app already available on iTunes.You have to export the distribution certificate p12 file from clients mac to use that distribution certificate.

Comment: You don't literally need the same cert and provisioning profile. You can regenerate new ones for the same app ID.